# TreeSet in Java- clarification?

Tags: java

*I'm confused ( new to Java)*

I've [read](http://www.coderanch.com/t/532388/java/java/TreeSet-allowing-addition-unique-object) that :

> TreeSet doesn't actually use equals() at all. It uses compareTo()
>   instead - if compareTo() returns zero, that means the two objects are
>   "equal" as far as the TreeSet is concerned.

Great.

So I have :

```
public class User implements Comparable<User>
{
    String Username;
    String Password;


    @Override
    public int compareTo(User o)
    {
        return o.Username.compareTo(this.Username );
    }
}
```

I also have :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TreeSet<User> ts = new TreeSet<User>();
        User u = new User();
        u.Username="u";
        ts.add(u);

        User u1 = new User();
        u1.Username="u";
        ts.add(u1);  //<---------------
        System.out.print(u1.compareTo(u)); //0


    }
```

Looking at debug : `compareTo` - returns "0". ( They have the same order)

If so :

**Question**

Why don't I get an exception when I insert 2 "same ordered" elements ?

Comment: Length of `ts` is 1. BTW: If you dont like to inherit `implements Comparable<User>`, you can use a different constructor: `new TreeSet<User>(new Comparable<User>)`.

Comment: @PeterRader it's more like  : if you can't inherit.... :-)

Comment: Why would you get an exception?  Instead `add` return false, as documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just see the docs of [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)) method in `TreeSet`.

> If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

You second element(*u1*) not **actually** added into the `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exception when you add two identical elements to any `Set`. The first addition would return `true`

```
boolean addU = ts.add(u); // returns true
```

while the second would return `false`

```
boolean addU1 = ts.add(u1);  // returns false
```

Note that your test makes it hard to see what happens when `compareTo` is inconsistent with `equals`, because you rely on `compareTo` method of `java.lang.String`, which is consistent with `equals`.

Comment: CAn you please go to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60411/room-for-royi-namir-and-dasblinkenlight) ?